# Django jQuery ajax post to https fails

Tags: django, jquery, google-chrome-extension, tastypie

I'm writing a chrome extension that use GET and POST ajax calls to an api made with Django and Tastypie.

GET ajax calls are successful and I can access data. However POST calls are failing only in production because the api is hosted with https://, in local environment it works (htt://localhost:8000).

I am providing a correct *CSRF token* in the header.
It seems that the error is happening here: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py#L259 where the api require a *Referer* header to check that the call is secure.

It does not seem possible to set in my ajax headers the *Referer* value directly, only if the name of the header starts with `X-`.

Thanks in advance for any solutions or tips to solve this issue.

Maxime.

Comment: "*It seems*". You should find out exactly where it returns.

Comment: This is sure. It returns false here https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py#L259 because the header Referer is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that check is explained in the [original source of that method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py?source=c#L133):

```
# Suppose user visits http://example.com/
# An active network attacker (man-in-the-middle, MITM) sends a
# POST form that targets https://example.com/detonate-bomb/ and
# submits it via JavaScript.
#
# The attacker will need to provide a CSRF cookie and token, but
# that's no problem for a MITM and the session-independent
# nonce we're using. So the MITM can circumvent the CSRF
# protection. This is true for any HTTP connection, but anyone
# using HTTPS expects better! For this reason, for
# https://example.com/ we need additional protection that treats
# http://example.com/ as completely untrusted. Under HTTPS,
# Barth et al. found that the Referer header is missing for
# same-domain requests in only about 0.2% of cases or less, so
# we can use strict Referer checking.
```

So, you may or may not benefit from the referrer check - it's up to you to decide.

If you wish to override it, just set your models to authenticate using a subclass of `SessionAuthentication`, and override the `is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs)` function to your needs. The original method is quite succinct, so honestly I'd just copy-paste it and remove the offending `if request.is_secure():` block rather than tricking the superclass into thinking the request has a referrer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also skip checking the referer in AJAX calls by making the request object think it was not made by a secure call. That way, you keep your CSRF checks and everything else, just skip the referer. Here's a sample middleware:

```
class UnsecureAJAX(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        setattr(request, '_is_secure_default', request._is_secure)
        def _is_secure():
            if request.is_ajax():
                return False
            else:
                return request._is_secure_default()
        setattr(request, '_is_secure', _is_secure)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also now technically possible to change the `Referer` part of a request with `webRequest` API.

You would need an `onBeforeSendHeaders` listener with `["blocking", "requestHeaders"]` options, and corresponding permissions. Then you can intercept your own requests and modify the header.